# How to install Homebrew on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, homebrew, r

How can i install Homebrew or R on a mavericks machine? I tried looking at [this link.](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation)

---

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [homebrew homepage](http://brew.sh) has a single step instalation:

paste

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"`

into terminal and hit <kbd>return</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Will this command work with iTerm?

Comment: Not sure. I did it with Terminal.app. My guess is that it will work, but I can't confirm for sure.

Comment: This will work in either iTerm or Terminal.